# blobstore fetch multiple items

Tags: python, google-app-engine, blobstore

```
class ViewPhotoHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreDownloadHandler):
    def get(self, photo_key):
        profile_id = string.strip(  string_after( self.request.path,"/view_photo/") ) 
        logging.info("ViewPhotoHandler profile_id=%s" % profile_id)
        user=None
        blob_keys=[]
        if profile_id:
            user = User.get_by_id( long( profile_id )) 
            blob_keys=user.blob_keys
        logging.info("ViewPhotoHandler blob_keys %s "%blob_keys)
        self.response.headers['Content-Type']="plain/text"

        for photo_key in blob_keys:
            blob_info = blobstore.get(photo_key)
            logging.info("ViewPhotoHandler photo_key %s blob_info %s " % (photo_key,blob_info))
            if blob_info:
                self.send_blob(blob_info)
```

This code works for one but not for two photos.
I got the correct keys in the logging.

When I send two it complains about 
`File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\webapp\blobstore_handlers.py", line 298, in send_blob
    del self.response.headers['Content-Type']`

What exactly does `send_blob` do under the hood ?

Comment: The create url handles one image at a time, create multiple urls for multiple images

Comment: indeed, need multiple urls for download, works now tx